# No module named 'vis_utils'

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
from skimage import transform
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from vis_utils import *
import random
import math
```

I am getting the error below:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10608/4005546520.py in <module>
      8 import numpy as np
      9 from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
---> 10 from vis_utils import *
     11 import random
     12 import math

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vis_utils'
```

Comment: Looks like you did not install `vis_utils`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to install the `vis_utils` module https://www.npmjs.com/package/vis-utils